# The value of $\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T} e^{ikt} dt$ when $T \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: mathematical-physics, quantum-information

I have this integral $\left(\dfrac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T} e^{ikt} dt\right)$ when $T \rightarrow \infty$, in an equation that I am studying, and it seems that this integration gives a value of $\dfrac{\delta(k)}{2}$. I would like to know how it computes to this result. $T$ is a quantization time period that goes to infinity.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by $\delta(k)$?

Comment: @Luftbahnfahrer Dirac delta distribution. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html

Comment: If that is what is meant, @maho should be careful as the Dirac delta function is not a "value".

Comment: It's possible that you meant to ask how to evaluate this expression: $
\int_0^\infty e^{ikt}dt$. This is the [Fourier transform of the step function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierTransformHeavisideStepFunction.html), which does indeed look like the Dirac delta function.

Comment: $\delta(k)$ is the Dirack delta. To give more context to the problem, this integration appears when I integrate (over time) the momentum flux operator to obtain the momentum operator, where the momentum flux operator contains the multiplication of two quantized electromagnetic fields. The $e^{ikx}$ in this case is $e^{i \Delta w t}$, where $\Delta w$ is the frequency matching condition for the nonlinear optical process, then I noticed that the $1/T\int_{0}^{T} e^{i \Delta w t} dt$ becomes $\delta(\Delta w)/2$, which is the conservation of energy, such that only $\Delta w$ is allowed.

Comment: Your observation that the Dirac delta appears is incorrect as stated. If you remove the $\frac{1}{T}$, then the integral in question is the Fourier transform of the step function, which does have a Dirac delta pop out. See the link in my other comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $k\neq 0$, note that
$$\int_0^Te^{ikt}dt = 
\frac{1}{ik}e^{ikt}
\bigg|_0^T = \frac{e^{ikT} - 1}{ik}.
$$
Taking the absolute values, note that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{T\to \infty}\left|\frac{1}{T}\int_0^Te^{ikt}dt\right| &= \lim_{T\to \infty}\frac{1}{kT}\left|e^{ikT}-1\right|\\
&\leq \lim_{T\to \infty}\frac{2}{kT} \\&= 0.
\end{align*}
In the case when $k=0$, the integrand is constant (it takes the value 1 everywhere) and
$$
\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^T dt = 1.
$$

Comment: Notice that $T$ should approach $\infty$ not zero, and $k$ can be zero, actually the integral gives a nonzero value only when $k=0$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my typo. I fixed the typo (replaced zero with $\infty$ in the limit), but otherwise the math in my answer is correct. My answer shows that the value is indeed nonzero only when k=0. But it is not the Dirac delta.

Comment: I see. I think the term 1/2 doesn't come from the integral I mentioned, I might be missing something else in my calculations. Thank you for you answer.

Comment: If you provide a link to the source of your problem (or provide more details) then we can help you understand more.